# Error using mediation package with lme4 model: mediator model is not yet implemented

Tags: r, lme4

I have a `data.frame`, `df`:

```
> str(df_ss)
'data.frame':   571 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ final_grade  : num  0.733 0.187 0.502 0.194 0.293 ...
 $ time_spent   : num  -0.2 -0.326 -0.709 -0.168 -0.254 ...
 $ gender_female: num  1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ course_ID    : Factor w/ 26 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 14 18 13 21 24 15 3 24 9 13 ...
```

I am trying to see how `time_spent` moderates the relationship between `gender_female` and `final_grade`. I'm specifying a random effect for `course_ID`.

The models I specified using are as follows:

```
med.fit <- lme4::lmer(time_spent ~ gender_female + (1|course_ID), data = df)
out.fit <- lme4::lmer(final_grade ~ time_spent + gender_female + (1|course_ID), data = df_ss)
```

Those seemed to work fine.

Following an example using the `lme4` package [in a vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mediation/vignettes/mediation.pdf) for the `mediation` package, I specified this mediation model:

```
library(mediation)
med.out <- mediate(med.fit, out.fit, treat = "gender_female", mediator = "time_spent", dropobs = T)
```

This led to this error output: `Error in mediate(med.fit, out.fit, treat = "gender_female", mediator = "time_spent",: mediator model is not yet implemented`.

Per [this mailing list question](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/mediation-information/2016-August.txt) (and answer), I checked that:

1. `inherits(mediatorModel, "merMod")` returned `TRUE` and
2. `getCall(mediatorModel)[[1]]` returned `lme4::lmer`

Comment: Instead of `lme4::lmer`, you might try loading `lme4` using `library(lme4)`, then just call `lmer`. Looking at the `mediate` code shows that the error-handling checks are looking for an exact match for `lmer` i.e. `getCall(model.m)[[1]] == "lmer"`.

Comment: If this suggestion doesn't work, please include some sample data that allows us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: That did the trick. Chaned to `library(lme4)`, then just call `lmer`. Thank you.

Comment: Great. I've copied my comment as an answer so that we can close this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `lme4::lmer`, you might try loading `lme4` using `library(lme4)`, then just call `lmer`. Looking at the `mediate` code shows that the error-handling checks are looking for an exact match for `lmer` i.e. `getCall(model.m)[[1]] == "lmer"`.