# Error using mediation package with lme4 model: mediator model is not yet implemented - previous answer does not work for me

Tags: r, lme4

Hi I am new to R and this forum.
I have the same problem as [a previous poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41253257/error-using-mediation-package-with-lme4-model-mediator-model-is-not-yet-impleme), but mine was not resolved with the answer. I get the message: "mediator model is not yet implemented" when I try to run a multilevel mediation model using package lme4 and mediation.

My data:

```
data.frame':    25383 obs. of  115 variables:
$ PID                        : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ T0_AGE                     : num  66.6 79.7 85.6 87 79.9 67.4 80 72 80.1 
68$ T0_ASEXE                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "Male","Female": 1 1...
$ T0_ALIVING_R               : num  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 ...
$ T0_educationcat            : Factor w/ 3 levels "high","middle",..
$ FI_morbidity_corrected     : num  0.0625 0 0.125 0.0625 0.0625 0.125 ……
$ FI_SRH                     : num  0.5 0.375 0.75 0.625 0.375…."
```

I am trying to see how `FI_morbidity_corrected` mediates the relationship between `T0_educationcat` and `FI_SRH`. I'm specifying a random intercept for `PID` (project ID) as data is clustered in different studies/projects. I am controlling for confounders `T0_ASEXE + T0_AGE + T0_ALIVING_R`

```
med.fit <- lmer(FI_morbidity_corrected~T0_educationcat + T0_ASEXE + T0_AGE + 
T0_ALIVING_R + (1|PID),data=topicsmds)
out.fit <- lmer(FI_SRH~FI_morbidity_corrected + T0_educationcat + T0_ASEXE + 
T0_AGE + T0_ALIVING_R + (1|PID),data=topicsmds)
```

This works, but then:

```
med23.out <- mediate(med.fit, out.fit, treat = "T0_educationcat", mediator = 
"FI_morbidity_corrected", control.value = "high", treat.value = "middle", 
sims = 100)
summary(med23.out)
```

and

```
med24.out <- mediate(med.fit, out.fit, treat = "T0_educationcat", mediator = 
"FI_morbidity_corrected", control.value = "high", treat.value = "low", sims 
= 100)
summary(med24.out)
```

Give me the error:

> mediator model is not yet implemented

I have loaded the lme4 pakage using `library(lme4)` as suggested, but still get this error.

`inherits(mediatorModel, "merMod")` returned TRUE

`getCall(mediatorModel)[[1]]` returned lme4::lmer

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Are you loading the package `lmerTest`? If so, `class(med.fit[[1]])` returns `merModLmerTest` instead of `lmerMod` - but the mediation package expects the latter. Unloading `lmerTest` would solve the problem.

Comment: +1. Worked for me. Though some people may want to know I had to then re-estimate `med.fit` and `out.fit` (having called `detach_package(lmerTest)`) before again calling `mediate` for it to work. Might save someone a few minutes.

Comment: I used the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979917/how-to-unload-a-package-without-restarting-r) `detach_package()` function.